# Rank binary tree structure in total binary trees for node count n

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, trees

`In general, if there are n nodes, there exist (2n)!/(n+1)! different tree`

Is it possible to define an order function os(r,n) = rth structure of binary tree, where n = node count and r E (0,   (2n)!/(n+1)!].

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Could it be reopened, this is not about full binary trees.